# How to find the minimum value in a postgres sql column which contains jsonb data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `t` in postgres database. It has a column `data` which contains jsonb data in the following format (for each record)-

```
{
  "20161214": {"4": ["3-14", "5-16", "642"], "9": ["3-10", "5-10", "664"] },
  "20161217": {"3": ["3-14", "5-16", "643"], "7": ["3-10", "5-10", "661"] } 
}
```

where `20161214` is the date, `"4"` is the month, `642` is the amount.

I need to find the minimum amount for each record of the table and the month that amount belongs to.

What I have tried:

Using jsonb_each function and separating key value pairs and then using min function.But still I cant get the month it belongs to.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Is the amount **always** the third element in the array?

Comment: I'm note sure what is the exact requirement so I wrote you 2 solutions, please take a look and see if any of them fits.

Comment: Yes,amount is always the third element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  j2.date
       ,j2.month
       ,j2.amount

from    t 

        left join lateral  

           (select      j1.date
                       ,j2.month
                       ,(j2.value->>2)::numeric  as amount

            from        jsonb_each (t.data) j1 (date,value) 

                        left join lateral jsonb_each (j1.value) j2 (month,value)
                        on true

            order by    amount

            limit       1   
            ) j2

        on true
```

---

```
+----------+-------+--------+
| date     | month | amount |
+----------+-------+--------+
| 20161214 | 4     | 642    |
+----------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Thats what I needed,Thanks a lot Dudu!

Comment: Can you please explain me the query a lil bit ? Why certain things are used, like limit 1

Comment: Execute the query without the limit

Comment: Hi Dudu,How can we change the above query to get minimum value from each date,like for date 20161214, 642 and for date 20161217, 643?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (without joins):

```
select
    min(case when amount = min_amount then month end) as month,
    min_amount as amout
from (
    select
        key as month,
        (select min((value->>2)::int) from jsonb_each(value)) as amount,
        min((select min((value->>2)::int) from jsonb_each(value))) over(partition by rnum) as min_amount,
        rnum
    from (
        select
            (jsonb_each(data)).*,
            row_number() over() as rnum
        from t
    ) t
) t
 group by
     rnum, min_amount;
```